# Is it possible to use default keyboards on the device for AirConsole?

Tags: airconsole

Using the Airconsole plugin for Construct.

I added a text input to the controller.html and it opens up my default android keyboard when I click it. Yet when I type, none of the keys are recognized (except space). I can paste into it though.

Do I have to use the keyboard code that Airconsole has in their Github, or is there a way to use default device keyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirConsole recommends to use the AirConsole keyboard

https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-keyboard

as it solves some problems like falling out of the fullscreen.